# Redux state changes between actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using `redux-logger` to see the **previous** and **after** of the redux's state. My problem is that my state seems to be changing before an action is dispatched:

Here it shows how the **after** state does update (the placementName property is correctly assigned)

[image: Here it shows how the **after** state does update (the placementName property is correctly assigned)]

[image: Here it shows that the **prev** state changes with the placementName property, so the previous **next** state is NOT the same as the current **prev** state, and they always should be]

Here it shows that the **prev** state changes with the placementName property, so the previous **next** state is NOT the same as the current **prev** state, and they always should be...

If I open and close the object in the chrome console it re-evaluates it and then the previous **next** state is the same as the **prev** of the current state.. I don't know what is changing it! I can't update the redux state using it's previous data because it always gets overwritten.

I'm using `redux-persist` to keep the user logged in using server side rendering with React:

```
const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={ store }>
        <PersistGate persistor={ persistor }>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Component />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};
```

configureStore():

```
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
  // Add redux-persist's configuration
  const config = {
    transforms: [immutableTransform()],
    key: 'root',
    storage
  };

const reducer = combineReducers(rootReducer);
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(config, reducer);

// Export the persistor as well
  let persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { persistor, store };
```

I'm not sure is `redux-persist` has anything to do with the problem though...

**EDIT**

Here's my reducer

```
[SAVE_INPUTS]: (state, {toSaveInputs}) => {
    const savedInputs = state.get('savedInputs');
    console.log("\n\nREDUX!\n\n");
// This line here prints the 'new' state before even returning it...
    console.log("Saved Inputs State: ", savedInputs);
    console.log("To save Inputs: ", toSaveInputs);

    const newSavedInputs = [...savedInputs, toSaveInputs];

    return state.merge(Map({
      savedInputs: newSavedInputs
    }));
  },
```

The result of this should be that the `toSaveInputs` is added to the `savedInputs` array in the redux state, but what it does is that it replaces the previous state's array with the new input and then in add the new `toSaveInputs`

Comment: You must have a mutation somewhere in your reducers (like `.push()` instead of `.concat()` on arrays or direct modification of an object property instead of `Object.assign()` and re-create a new object.

Comment: I don't see it, I'll edit to add the reducer